# Using Linux to create/remove mac partition

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning

Rev0

I am trying to remove malware on my computers and in search of the source of persistence*, I have tried different approaches, one being to format the storage device with a mac partition table via Ubuntu.  When I generate a new mac partition table, there appears an unknown 31.5kB partition labeled /dev/sda1 but I can't do anything with it.  Is this partition normal when implementing a mac partition table on a Linux platform?

*Malware remains after complete low level formatting.

Rev 1 - Added additional information in the screen shot below, provided by GParted.

[image: Gparted-Additional Info. 1]

[image: Gparted-Additional Info. 2]

Comment: 'low level formatting' .. how did you do that? From Recovery or Internet recovery? Total nuke or just re-initialised the partition? How are you restoring?

Comment: I've used programs such as Active Killdisk DBAN and many others to destroy the data on the drive and not restored.  After I generate the mac partition table with GParted, the 31,5kB partition shows up with a yellow explanation point next to the partition and the information provided by right clicking and selecting "information" is as listed below.

Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda1 is missing

Comment: I do not know why you resorted to linux to do this.  My first question is do you really have malware on your system?  Should have run etrecheck and malwarebytes to check out your machine. You can do what you want from a network boot.  See https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/25/how-to-start-up-your-mac-in-internet-recovery-mode/   I format the disk to 2 partitions.  I then reformat to one partition.

Comment: I think when you declare a partition of a fixed size, there could be some left over space.  It could be that partitions always want to start on some boundary.  The unused size could mean the space was left over between two partitions.  There are a lot of hidden partitions in mac os.

Comment: I would not recommend partitioning in linux unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @historystamp  It isn't that I've resorted to using Linux to partition my drive, this was only an experiment and after seeing the 31kB partition appear when GParted finished creating the partition table, it raised a red flag for me.  I am not running a mac system; primarily Windows 10 but have been trying Ubuntu the past couple of months.

The only steps that I took before raising my question on this site was to delete the existing partitions on my drive (previous Ubuntu install) and generate a mac partition table.  I had not set up any partitions.

Comment: @historystamp  To answer your question about the malware, yes, I am 100% positive that my devices are infected with malware.